# Jenkins html publisher Failed to extract

Tags: batch-file, ant, jenkins, report

I am trying to execute an ant report throw Jenkins.It all works fine until the html publisher starts.It looks like it can not Extract the html files from folder.
The ant report is called from a bat file.Here is the output:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 minutes 31 seconds
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level C:\WiboxTesting\NPO testing\build\reports\tests to        /.jenkins/jobs/GUI_Testing/htmlreports/WiBox_Testing
FATAL: HTML Publisher failure
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Failed to extract C:\WiboxTesting\NPO    testing\build\reports\tests/**/*

at hudson.FilePath.readFromTar(FilePath.java:2088)
at hudson.FilePath.copyRecursiveTo(FilePath.java:2000)
at hudson.FilePath.copyRecursiveTo(FilePath.java:1911)
at hudson.FilePath.copyRecursiveTo(FilePath.java:1894)
at htmlpublisher.HtmlPublisher.perform(HtmlPublisher.java:213)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:785)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:757)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:706)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1703)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)

Caused by: java.io.IOException
at hudson.remoting.FastPipedInputStream.read(FastPipedInputStream.java:175)
at hudson.util.HeadBufferingStream.read(HeadBufferingStream.java:61)
at com.jcraft.jzlib.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:175)
at com.jcraft.jzlib.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.tar.TarBuffer.readBlock(TarBuffer.java:257)
at org.apache.tools.tar.TarBuffer.readRecord(TarBuffer.java:223)
at hudson.org.apache.tools.tar.TarInputStream.getNextEntry(TarInputStream.java:228)
at hudson.FilePath.readFromTar(FilePath.java:2066)
... 13 more

at hudson.FilePath.copyRecursiveTo(FilePath.java:2007)
at hudson.FilePath.copyRecursiveTo(FilePath.java:1911)
at hudson.FilePath.copyRecursiveTo(FilePath.java:1894)
at htmlpublisher.HtmlPublisher.perform(HtmlPublisher.java:213)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:785)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:757)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:706)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1703)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Error: Failed to deserialize the    Callable object.
at hudson.remoting.Channel$3.adapt(Channel.java:755)
at hudson.remoting.Channel$3.adapt(Channel.java:750)
at hudson.remoting.FutureAdapter.get(FutureAdapter.java:59)
at hudson.FilePath.copyRecursiveTo(FilePath.java:2003)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Failed to deserialize the Callable object.
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:104)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:63)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler.isAuthenticated(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ChildElement.checkResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.checkResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDefaultSerialFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerialFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$800(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.deserialize(UserRequest.java:182)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:98)
... 8 more
```

Knows someone what is the problem ? Or how can I do this in another way ?

Thanks !